# Error in playerindex

Tags: c#, xna, sharpdx

I'm trying to port my game from XNA to SharpDX, but I can't find the solution for my problem:

```
namespace TomShane.Neoforce.Central
{       
    public class InputState
    {
        #region Fields

        public const int MaxInputs = 4;

        public readonly KeyboardState[] CurrentKeyboardStates;
     //   public readonly GamePadState[] CurrentGamePadStates;

        public readonly KeyboardState[] LastKeyboardStates;
   //     public readonly GamePadState[] LastGamePadStates;
        public readonly KeyboardManager Keyboard;

      //  public readonly bool[] GamePadWasConnected;

       // public TouchCollection TouchState;

        //public readonly List<GestureSample> Gestures = new List<GestureSample>();

        #endregion

        #region Initialization


        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new input state.
        /// </summary>
        public InputState()
        {
            CurrentKeyboardStates = new KeyboardState[MaxInputs];
        //    CurrentGamePadStates = new GamePadState[MaxInputs];

            LastKeyboardStates = new KeyboardState[MaxInputs];
          //  LastGamePadStates = new GamePadState[MaxInputs];

            //GamePadWasConnected = new bool[MaxInputs];
        }


        #endregion

        #region Public Methods


        /// <summary>
        /// Reads the latest state of the keyboard and gamepad.
        /// </summary>
        public void Update()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MaxInputs; i++)
            {
                LastKeyboardStates[i] = CurrentKeyboardStates[i];
         //       LastGamePadStates[i] = CurrentGamePadStates[i];

                CurrentKeyboardStates[i] = Keyboard.GetState();
//                CurrentGamePadStates[i] = GamePad.GetState((PlayerIndex)i);

                // Keep track of whether a gamepad has ever been
                // connected, so we can detect if it is unplugged.
                //if (CurrentGamePadStates[i].IsConnected)
                //{
                //    GamePadWasConnected[i] = true;
                //}
            }

         //   TouchState = TouchPanel.GetState();

            //Gestures.Clear();
            //while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
            //{
            //    Gestures.Add(TouchPanel.ReadGesture());
            //}

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper for checking if a key was newly pressed during this update. The
        /// controllingPlayer parameter specifies which player to read input for.
        /// If this is null, it will accept input from any player. When a keypress
        /// is detected, the output playerIndex reports which player pressed it.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsNewKeyPress(Keys key, PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer,
                                            out PlayerIndex playerIndex)
        {
            if (controllingPlayer.HasValue)
            {
                // Read input from the specified player.
                playerIndex = controllingPlayer.Value;

              int i = (int)playerIndex;
               // int i = playerIndex;
                return (CurrentKeyboardStates[i].IsKeyDown(key) &&
                        LastKeyboardStates[i].IsKeyPressed(key));
                        //IsKeyUp(key));
            }
            else
            {
                // Accept input from any player.
                return (IsNewKeyPress(key, PlayerIndex.One, out playerIndex)); //||
                       // IsNewKeyPress(key, PlayerIndex.Two, out playerIndex) ||
                      //  IsNewKeyPress(key, PlayerIndex.Three, out playerIndex) ||
                       // IsNewKeyPress(key, PlayerIndex.Four, out playerIndex));
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper for checking if a button was newly pressed during this update.
        /// The controllingPlayer parameter specifies which player to read input for.
        /// If this is null, it will accept input from any player. When a button press
        /// is detected, the output playerIndex reports which player pressed it.
        /// </summary>



        /// <summary>
        /// Checks for a "menu select" input action.
        /// The controllingPlayer parameter specifies which player to read input for.
        /// If this is null, it will accept input from any player. When the action
        /// is detected, the output playerIndex reports which player pressed it.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsMenuSelect(PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer,
                                 out PlayerIndex playerIndex)
        {
            return IsNewKeyPress(Keys.Space, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex) ||
                   IsNewKeyPress(Keys.Enter, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex);

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Checks for a "menu cancel" input action.
        /// The controllingPlayer parameter specifies which player to read input for.
        /// If this is null, it will accept input from any player. When the action
        /// is detected, the output playerIndex reports which player pressed it.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsMenuCancel(PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer,
                                 out PlayerIndex playerIndex)
        {
            return IsNewKeyPress(Keys.Escape, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex); 
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Checks for a "menu up" input action.
        /// The controllingPlayer parameter specifies which player to read
        /// input for. If this is null, it will accept input from any player.
        /// </summary>
       public bool IsMenuUp(PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer)
        {
            PlayerIndex playerIndex;

            return IsNewKeyPress(Keys.Up, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex);

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Checks for a "menu down" input action.
        /// The controllingPlayer parameter specifies which player to read
        /// input for. If this is null, it will accept input from any player.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsMenuDown(PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer)
        {
            PlayerIndex playerIndex;

            return IsNewKeyPress(Keys.Down, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex);// ||
                 //  IsNewButtonPress(Buttons.DPadDown, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex) ||
                  // IsNewButtonPress(Buttons.LeftThumbstickDown, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Checks for a "pause the game" input action.
        /// The controllingPlayer parameter specifies which player to read
        /// input for. If this is null, it will accept input from any player.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsPauseGame(PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer)
        {
            PlayerIndex playerIndex;

            return IsNewKeyPress(Keys.Escape, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex);// ||
                //   IsNewButtonPress(Buttons.Back, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex) ||
                  // IsNewButtonPress(Buttons.Start, controllingPlayer, out playerIndex);
        }


        #endregion
    }         
}
```

I'm getting this error. I don't know how fix it.

> Error 2   The type 'SharpDX.PlayerIndex' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable' C:\Users\Pedro\Dropbox\GAMES\NeoforceControls-SharpDX-master\Central\ScreenManager\InputState.cs    95  21  Central
>   Error   3   The type 'SharpDX.PlayerIndex' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable' C:\Users\Pedro\Dropbox\GAMES\NeoforceControls-SharpDX-master\Central\ScreenManager\InputState.cs    156 21  Central
>   Error   4   The type 'SharpDX.PlayerIndex' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable' C:\Users\Pedro\Dropbox\GAMES\NeoforceControls-SharpDX-master\Central\ScreenManager\InputState.cs    172 21  Central
>   Error   5   The type 'SharpDX.PlayerIndex' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable' C:\Users\Pedro\Dropbox\GAMES\NeoforceControls-SharpDX-master\Central\ScreenManager\InputState.cs    186 20  Central
>   Error   6   The type 'SharpDX.PlayerIndex' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable' C:\Users\Pedro\Dropbox\GAMES\NeoforceControls-SharpDX-master\Central\ScreenManager\InputState.cs    201 21  Central
>   Error   7   The type 'SharpDX.PlayerIndex' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable' C:\Users\Pedro\Dropbox\GAMES\NeoforceControls-SharpDX-master\Central\ScreenManager\InputState.cs    216 21  Central
>   Error   8   Cannot convert type 'SharpDX.PlayerIndex' to 'int'  C:\Users\Pedro\Dropbox\GAMES\NeoforceControls-SharpDX-master\Central\ScreenManager\InputState.cs    103 23  Central
>   Error   9   The out parameter 'playerIndex' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method    C:\Users\Pedro\Dropbox\GAMES\NeoforceControls-SharpDX-master\Central\ScreenManager\InputState.cs    159 13  Central
>   Error   10  The out parameter 'playerIndex' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method    C:\Users\Pedro\Dropbox\GAMES\NeoforceControls-SharpDX-master\Central\ScreenManager\InputState.cs    175 13  Central

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlayerIndex?` means that it can be null or contain a value. It's a synonym to `Nullable<PlayerIndex>`.

You can either change it to `PlayerIndex` or, when using it, use it as `playerIndex.Value` so you refer to the value it *may* be containing, you can also check if this is the case before using it by checking the `HasValue` property of the type.

More info on nullable types [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

If that doesn't help, try to be more specific on the line of code throwing the error, instead of copying the whole thing.

Comment: topico can be close